# Chi-square test when two cells are zero in the chisq.test() function

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have following simulated test for chisq.test() in R

```
> dd <- data.frame(a=sample(1,size=100,replace=T),
+                  group=sample(1:2,size=100,replace=T,prob = c(0.3,0.7)))
> dl <- data.frame(a=sample(1:2,size=100,replace=T),
+                  group=sample(1:2,size =100,replace=T,prob = c(0.3,0.7)))
> table(dd)
   group
a    1  2
  1 32 68
> chisq.test(table(dd))

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  table(dd)
X-squared = 12.96, df = 1, p-value = 0.0003182

> table(dl)
   group
a    1  2
  1 21 33
  2  9 37
> chisq.test(table(dl))

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  table(dl)
X-squared = 3.5446, df = 1, p-value = 0.05974
```

I intend to compare the differece between group=1 against group=2; the calculation was correctly done in dl. However, in dd, because all individuals in both groups contain 100% events (all of individuals have the same a class); there should be no difference between the two groups (p=1), but the chisq.test() gives a p value of 0.0003, which is supposed to compare the difference of the proportion (32% vs. 68%). But what I really want to compare is the proportion within groups (100% vs. 100%). in this case how can I correctly use chisq.test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your columns to factors and specify the levels they can take.  That way it can be known that there are empty cells.

```
dd[,1] <- factor(dd[,1], levels = 1:2)
dd[,2] <- factor(dd[,2], levels = 1:2)
```

which gives

```
> chisq.test(table(dd))

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  table(dd)
X-squared = NaN, df = 1, p-value = NA

Warning message:
In chisq.test(table(dd)) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

which might not be exactly what you want but is more correct than doing a test that each group has the same probability.